# How to get road/street name instead of state route?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am using the google maps API to get the address of a geolocation successfully however it will often substitute the name of a road or street with state route. This is confusing because we do not use state route we use the road/ street names.

I cant find an option to request street names instead of state route either.

The following is what I have tried: 
The current method which is returning the state route.

```
function getAddress() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (location) {
        mrtlat = location.coords.latitude;
        mrtlong = location.coords.longitude;

        varStore.mrtlatlng = mrtlat + "," + mrtlong;

        varStore.url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=" + varStore.mrtlatlng + "&key= ";
        $.getJSON(varStore.url, function (data) {

            var address = data.results[0].formatted_address;
            varStore.location = address;
            console.log(varStore.location);
            new Messi('Current Location detected is <br>' + varStore.mrtlatlng + '<br/>' + varStore.location, {
                title: 'Approximate Location', modal: true,
                buttons: [{ id: 0, label: 'Close', val: 'X' }]
            });
        });
    });
}
```

The second method, flawed because it does not always return a street address. I have limited it to the first three objects to try and retain location accuracy:

```
function getAddress3() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (location) {

        varStore.mrtlatlng = location.coords.latitude + "," + location.coords.longitude;

        varStore.url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=" + varStore.mrtlatlng + "&key= ";
        $.getJSON(varStore.url, function (data) {
            // The following block of code tests the first 3 for State route and will set the address to the first one that does not contain state route 
            // Needs to be cleaned up

            var k = 0;
            var foundValid = false;
            var address = data.results[0].formatted_address;
            while (k <3 && foundValid == false) {
                if (data.results[k].formatted_address.includes("State Route")) {
                    if (data.results[k].address_components[1].long_name.includes("State Route") == false) {

                    }
                    k++;
                } else {
                    foundValid = true;
                    address = data.results[k].formatted_address + "<br/> Found valid address";
                    console.log(data.results[k].address_components[0].short_name);
                    console.log(data.results[k].address_components[0].long_name);
                    console.log("true");
                }
            } 
            if (foundValid == true) {
                //do nothing 
            } else {
                address = data.results[0].formatted_address + "<br/> Could not find valid address";


            address = data.results[0].address_components

            varStore.location = address;
            console.log(varStore.location);
            new Messi('Current Location detected is <br>' + varStore.mrtlatlng + '<br/>' + varStore.location, {
                title: 'Approximate Location', modal: true,
                buttons: [{ id: 0, label: 'Close', val: 'X' }]
            });
        };
    });
}
)}
```

Otherwise there is the final method which failed terribly:

```
varStore.url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=" + varStore.mrtlatlng + "&key= ";
        $.getJSON(varStore.url, function (data) {
            var address = "";
            if (data.results[0].address_components[1].long_name.includes("State Route") == false) {
                address = data.results[0].address_components[0].long_name + " "// house 
                        + data.results[0].address_components[1].long_name + " " //street
                        + data.results[0].address_components[2].long_name + " "//suburb
                        + data.results[0].address_components[3].short_name + " " //state
                        + data.results[0].address_components[5].short_name + " "//post
             } else if (data.results[3].address_components[1].long_name.includes("State Route") == false) {
                address = data.results[3].address_components[0] + " "// house 
                        + data.results[3].address_components[1].long_name + " " //street
                        + data.results[3].address_components[2].long_name + " "//suburb
                        + data.results[3].address_components[3].short_name + " " //state
                        + data.results[3].address_components[5].short_name + " "//post
             } else if (data.results[2].address_components[1].long_name.includes("State Route") == false) {
                address = data.results[2].address_components[0] + " "// house 
                        + data.results[2].address_components[1].long_name + " " //street
                        + data.results[2].address_components[2].long_name + " "//suburb
                        + data.results[2].address_components[3].short_name + " " //state
                        + data.results[2].address_components[5].short_name + " "//post
             } else {
                address = data.results[0].address_components[0] + " "// house 
                        + data.results[0].address_components[1].long_name + " " //street
                        + data.results[0].address_components[2].long_name + " "//suburb
                        + data.results[0].address_components[3].short_name + " " //state
                        + data.results[0].address_components[5].short_name + " "//post
            }
            //var address = data.results[0].formatted_address;
            varStore.location = address;
            console.log(varStore.location);
```

I know that it is possible as i can enter street names on to google maps and be returned the correct address instead of having to use state route.

Also being written for chrome.

Comment: Can you please provide an example, as I don't understand what the issue is. Let's take a look at e.g. this sample Geocoding request from Google: `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=40.714224,-73.961452&key=KEY` which returns as first result `281 Bedford Ave, Brooklyn, NY 11211, USA`. I understand you want to get the route's name, i.e. "Bedford Ave". You can get it when checking `address_components[x].types[x] === "route"`, is this what you mean?

Comment: I actually want to avoid route names at all costs and go with the long name for the road. Here is an example: latlng=-37.818182,%20145.19384    . In this example we are looking at Mitcham Rd however it is being called state route 36. This is for the first item. Is there any way I can convert the route number into road name?

Comment: Thanks I see. It looks though that the coordinates that correspond to `361 Mitcham Rd, Mitcham VIC 3132, Australia` are "-37.818291,145.193999" (place id `ChIJeUUC4Dw51moRWj4QXQxbIRs`). The geocoder does return the street name for it: https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#q%3D-37.818291%252C145.193999

Comment: I see, how come when I use "latlng=-37.818182,%20145.19384" it will return 361 State Route 36 as the address but moving the marker to that street address gives me Mitcham rd? When I am using my coordinates the address components give `               "long_name" : "State Route 36",
               "short_name" : "State Route 36",
               "types" : [ "route" ]
            `   do you have a recommendation as to how I could reliably get street names as opposed to route number?

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure I understand your question/issue. Your coordinates for that place are closer to State Route 36 / Brunswick Rd, that's why Geocoder returns those instead of Mitcham Rd. These are all street addresses names (routes) not numbers (?).